# Magento 2.4 EE - Consumers or RabbitMQ Consumers are not working, it should work automatically after deployment

Tags: magento2, magento2-enterprise, deployment, rabbit-mq, consumers

**Summary of the issue**

- Queue Consumers are not working, it should work automatically after deployment.

**Information on your environment**

- Magento EE 2.4 ,
- RabbitMQ 3.8,
- Composer version- 1.10.16
- Configuration -
  .magento.env.yaml

deploy:

```
       CRON_CONSUMERS_RUNNER:
           cron_run: true
           max_messages: 0
           consumers:
               - codegeneratorProcessor
```

**Steps to reproduce**

- Admin panel > Marketing > Cart Price rules > Add new rule > choose                       Coupon > Drop Down > Auto > Save
- Admin panel > Marketing > Cart Price rules > Edit Auto Tupe Rule > Manage Coupon Codes > Enter Coupon Qty > Generate > See                            Message is added to queue, wait to get your coupons soon
- bulk coupon not generated.

**Expected and actual results**

- codegeneratorProcessor queue should process and be able to generate bulk                              coupons.

Answer (score 0):

As per `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/etc/queue_consumer.xml`, the consumer `codegeneratorProcessor` is using db connection and not amqp (rabbit):

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/consumer.xsd">
    <consumer name="codegeneratorProcessor" queue="codegenerator" connection="db" maxMessages="5000" consumerInstance="Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Consumer" handler="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Consumer::process" />
</config>
```

so this has nothing to do with your connection to rabbitmq.

In order to start the consumers, you should read the documentation available here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-queue.html#start-message-queue-consumers and proceed with the described steps in executing and configurign the CLI command:

```sh
bin/magento queue:consumers:start [--max-messages=<value>] [--batch-size=<value>] [--single-thread] [--area-code=<value>] <consumer_name>
```

Good Luck!